# Customize browser certificate selector window

Tags: browser, certificate, customization, selector

due to my work I have many digital certificates on my computer and every time I enter a website where i need to use them I have to select a certificate and search in a tiny window for the correct one, on every browser like chrome, edge or firefox the usability of this pop up is terrible.

Is there any way to customize this, either with a plugin or editing browser files?

if i could have a digital certificate selector with a filter/searcher it would be great.

Thank you very much.

Tried with different browsers and github research but nothing usefull found